# How do I return a specific value to any property or function calls for an object?

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate the properties of an object based on a string.
But these property definitions might reference another object called '*actor*'.

If this *actor* exists (which is not always the case) my code works, if the *actor* does not exist (is undefined) I want the evaluation to return **NaN** for *actor*-dependant properties.

**Example:**

The property definition string might look like:

```
"name = 'pant leg insurance';
cost = 10;
useful = actor.hasPants();
max = actor._legs;"
```

These variables are defined before the definition string is run through

```
eval(propertyString);
```

If the *actor* exists everything is fine, but if the *actor* does not exist I want every *actor*-dependant value (in this case '*useful*' and '*max*') to return **NaN**.

I already researched a bit and found the **Proxy** object, but this only helps if I want to access a direct property of the *actor*, neither with functions nor with properties which are properties of properties [...] of the *actor*.

```js
var actor;
if (actor === undefined) {
  actor = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, property) {
      return NaN;
    }
  });
} 

console.log(actor.anything);
console.log(actor.anyfunction());
console.log(actor.anything.anything);
console.log(actor.anything.anyfunction());
```

How do I achieve that this snippet would return **NaN** for any property or function calls on *actor*?

Comment: have you tried method hasOwnProperty(); ?

Comment: @SenadMeškin the problem with that would be, that (If I understand it correctly) I need to add those calls to the property definition string. I would like to avoid that, because if I implement those checks in the propertyString I could directly use `useful = ((actor !== undefined) ? actor.hasPants() : NaN)` and it would be ideal if I didn't have to complicate the property definition strings.

Comment: Do you really need to use `eval()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, proxies cannot achieve this. When a property is accessed, you don't know whether it will be used directly in the assignment or will be called as a method, so you can't decide whether to return `NaN` or a function. There is no callable `NaN` value.

Instead, you will need to process your property definition string (you probably want to anyway, as assigning to undeclared variables is evil) and test each line for usage of `actor`, and when it does apply your if-not-exists-then-`NaN` logic.